# Development speed - Compiling mvc web application "on the fly"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, compilation

Moving to mvc 4 recently I'm wondering if there's way to speed up those "change a comma and update browser to see if it works" type of situations during developement.

Having programmed professionally for more than 10 years now I've gotten into certain habits.
For one I've been using mainly asp.net web site projects, webforms, which allows me to make changes to the code-behind, ctrl+s, alt-tab to browser, hit f5, and see the results.
Sometimes, but not always, it'll recycle the application, destroy my session, and send be back to the login page.

Working on a learning-by-doing mvc 4 project I'm getting slighly frustrated with the compilation cycle - I guess mostly because it's not what I'm used to.

As an example, let's say we're writing an Action to handle file moving and copying.

```
string rootpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/uploads");
string targetpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Path.Combine(rootpath, TargetDir.Substring(TargetDir.LastIndexOf("/"))));
```

This compiles fine, but when tested it throws an exception because "rootpath" is already absolute and cannot be mapped again.
Changing the code to

```
string rootpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/uploads");
string targetpath = Path.Combine(rootpath, TargetDir.Substring(TargetDir.LastIndexOf("/")));
```

also compiles fine and probably actually works. However you have one of those "what was I writing" moments and change it to

```
string rootpath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/uploads");
string targetpath = Path.Combine(rootpath, Path.GetDirectoryName(TargetDir));
```

For now all's good.

Compared to developing with web site projects, the steps of code change, wait for compilation, refresh browser, login, test functionality (and repeat) seems to take much longer than before.
Is there any way to speed up these types of trial-and-error situations?
Or am I simply going about it wrong?

Comment: Web site projects are uniquely strange. I recommend against using them, ever.

Comment: Well, thanks @John Saunders...but how is that comment constructive in any way?

Comment: It will hopefully keep you from using them again, saving you from a great deal of grief, and adding years to your life.

Comment: LOL. Thanks for looking out for me. I appreciate your interest in my health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a completely different approach. Use unit test.

The great advantage of MVC is that basically all code can be unit tested (controllers, models, ...).
In this way at each change you just run a single or a set of unit test (keyboard shortcut like Ctrl+R, Ctrl+L or similar keywords are your best friends for maximum speed :-) ).

Only at the end you will run the complete project to see the final output.

Of course other then speed up develpment/debug time you will also benefit of a full suite of tests that can be very useful during development (for a better design of your code) and for regression test.

Comment: I agree, except to add that properly written web forms code can also have all important parts unit tested.

Comment: I managed to get unit testing set up for the project. I can see how this makes sence, and may speed up debugging.  Had a bit of trouble with Server.MapPath, though. http://www.vfstech.com/?p=149 helped me out.